# StreamingContext does not have a constructor

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am dealing very basic Spark Streaming Scala code . Code is Given below

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
object TestStreamProcessor {

    def main(args: Array [String]) {

            val batchInterval = 5

                val sparkConfig = new SparkConf().setAppName("TestKinesisConsumer")
                val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConfig, batchInterval)
            ssc.start()
                ssc.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(batchIntervalSeconds * 5 * 1000)


    }
}
```

But getting below Error while building code using maven.

```
 error: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext does not have a constructor
[INFO]              val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConfig, batchInterval)
```

Did anyone faced this before ?

Answer (score 2):

So what exactly is your question? If you open the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/StreamingContext.html) you can see that the `batchDuration` argument is of type [`org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/Duration.html). Have you tried something like

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConfig, Seconds(batchInterval))
```